# varnish / nginx, cache decision based on object size

Tags: nginx, varnish

I want to restrict the size of the object that can be cached in varnish and nginx. The object crossing the restricted size, should be served to the viewer directly without being cached.

What is the best way do achieve this in varnish and nginx?

Thanks,

Viral

Answer (score 2):

Varnish 4.1:

You can achieve this using the 'std' VMOD.

Add this to your vcl config:

```
import std;
```

Then you can use it for example:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  # Increase TTL for files > 5 MB
  if (std.integer(beresp.http.Content-Length, 0) > 5242880) {
    set beresp.ttl = 4w;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using both Nginx and Varnish where Varnish is doing the actual caching.

If you can infer from the URL that a file is probably too large to cache then it's smart to bypass Varnish from nginx if the URL matches a specific pattern.

When a request is directed to Varnish you can do something like:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  // Don't cache files larger than 10M
  if (beresp.http.Content-Length ~ "[0-9]{7,}") {
    return (hit_for_pass);
  }
}
```

Alas all header values are strings, this makes it impossible to use comparison operators like > and <. In this case objects with a maximum size of 9.999.999 are served by the cache, other objects are sent from the backend-server without being cached. If you want another number than 10M you'll need to get creative with regexes. I'm assuming Varnish 3.0.